# Callback in an embedded ASP.NET webpage not working in Android, but so in iOS

Tags: android, asp.net, .net, xamarin

I have a Xamarin app that has embedded an ASP.NET web page. The thing is that I have one page that is a contact form which, once you click the "Send" button, shows a loading icon and it calls that same page but with a new header that contains "Yes" or "No", which leads to show a success message.

Both in Android and iOS the email gets sent, but in Android, the loading icon never leaves the screen, meaning that the page never reloads with the new header.

Thanks beforehand!

I modified both Xamarin and ASP.NET programs with no success, maybe it has something to do with Androids viewmodel or something like that, but I couldn't fix it yet.

This is the button OnClick event code:

```cs
if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(selectedEmail) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(asunto) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(body))
{
    // SendEmail is a function that uses SmtpClient to send the email
    if (await SendEmail(selectedEmail, asunto, body))
    {
        // The function returns true, so it runs these two lines.
        // the thing is that the button is not enabled and the
        // javascript function is not called
        // BUT, if the button is clicked two times, the email is sent
        // twice, but these two lines end up working
        this.btnEnviarEmail.Enabled = true;
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, typeof(Page), "notificarTrue", "NotifySuccess('3000');", true);
    }
    else
    {
        btnEnviarEmail.Enabled = true;
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, typeof(Page), "notificarFalse", "NotifyError('3000');", true);
    }
}
else
{
    btnEnviarEmail.Enabled = true;
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, typeof(Page), "notificarFalse", "NotifyError('3000');", true);
}
```

**Fixed!**
Don´t ask me why because unfortunately I don´t have a clear view on this, but:

- After a lot of playing around I realized that by unFocusing the last textBox where I wrote text (by clicking anywhere else) and then clicking the button, that lead to properly Enable the button and show the confirmation message, after the email was sent.
  I also removed comments on two lines that used to give me problems before but, for whatever reason, now they don´t:

```cs
base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
```

and

```cs
base.OnElementChanged(e);
```

Comment: Did you try it on different android device? And did this problem only appear on asp.net web page?

Comment: Yes, I've try it in different android devices, whose brand and OS versions differ from one another. And yes, this only happens in the ASP.NET web page

Comment: Can you show the details about how to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Yup, so I've found two things:
- First is that code behind is called completely and fault less but, the these two lines are not working:
```cs
```

Comment: (only on android):
```cs
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, typeof(Page), "notificarTrue", "NotifySuccess('3000');", true);
this.btnEnviarEmail.Enabled = true;
```
- And the other things is that if I click button twice, that two lines work properly.
Does this mean that Android WebView doesn't render these things until they are colled the second time?

Comment: Added the code. As I mentioned, when the button is clicked twice, the email gets sent twice, but this second time, the button is enabled and the javascript function gets called, which seems weird to me, like if Android webview blocks or doesnt load something until the object is called the second time.

Comment: Glad to know you have resolved it, you can add the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fixed!** Don´t ask me why because unfortunately I don´t have a clear view on this, but:

After a lot of playing around I realized that by unFocusing the last textBox where I wrote text (by clicking anywhere else) and then clicking the button, that lead to properly Enable the button and show the confirmation message, after the email was sent. I also removed comments on two lines that used to give me problems before but, for whatever reason, now they don´t:

```cs
base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
```

and

```cs
base.OnElementChanged(e);
```

So, basically, what I did is align the button to the bottom of the screen and make the form unscrollable, so the user must unhide the keyboard before clicking it. Not the best solution, but works like a charm!